# AngularJs - $cookies reflecting changes only after refresh on same state

Tags: angularjs, angular-cookies

I am using `$cookies` to store `userId` upon successful login from a `modalInstanceController` and then getting the `userId` in my `homepageController`. In the whole process the state of the app is not being changed and neither the page is reloaded.
Now when I console log the `userId` during this process it shows `undefined` but when I refresh the page the `userId` is shown perfectly.

I am pre-filling the form on successful login, so I don't want to reload my state. Any solution for this so that I can achieve that.

Code Snippet  :

`modalInstanceController`

```
 $scope.login = function() {
    utilities.login()
    .success(function(response) {
      $cookies.put('user_id', response.message.user_id);
    });
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
```

`homepageController`

```
$scope.userId = $cookies.get('user_id');
```

`userId` is only shown upon page refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no sign in your code that you are setting userId after receiving the information back from the server. The homepageController will only read the cookie when it is loaded

```
 $scope.login = function() {
    utilities.login()
    .success(function(response) {
      $cookies.put('user_id', response.message.user_id);
      // add next line
      $scope.userId = $cookies.get('user_id');
    });
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
 };
```

Comment: But my view is still not updating, it is being updated only after refreshing the page.

Comment: Can you post more details of the the structure of your app - maybe you need to use a Service/Factory to pass data from the login component to the others

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to share the data globally and also retaining the data after page refresh. If I use services, the data is not persistent after page reload and when I am using `localStorageService` and `$cookies`, then I need to reload the page for reflecting the changes.

Comment: A service will ensure that the data is available as you change routes